# why when I create an element in the DOM I get different information in the console

Tags: javascript

I have this code, first I create a link, then I add it to the created `p` element:

```
let editSectionLink = document.createElement("a");
editSectionLink.setAttribute("href", "#popup-edit-section");
editSectionLink.classList.add("popup-link");
editSectionLink.innerText = "Edit";

let p = document.createElement("p");
p.style.textAlign = "right";
p.appendChild(editSectionLink);
console.log(p);
```

In the console I get two types of results.
1:
[image]
2:
[image]
How to get the result like in the second picture because I need to get the DOM element?

Comment: when are you seeing the second one? I've checked now in my console and I only see the first image (just `p`)

Comment: The `console` API is a debugging aid. It is not intended to be a perfect reflection of the state of affairs for your code and data; there's not really even a real standard between browsers.

Comment: after reloading the page, I get a random result (1 picture or 2 picture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`console.dir()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/dir):

> The method `console.dir()` displays an interactive list of the properties of the specified JavaScript object. The output is presented as a hierarchical listing with disclosure triangles that let you see the contents of child objects.

So in your example it would be `console.dir(p)`.

Comment: OP is asking **why** is there a difference in the printed result, and this answer does not attempt to answer the very question itself